# How to test if two arrays share the same memory block?

Tags: julia

How do I test if two arrays points to the same memory block?
For example, I'd like a function `foo` that would work like this:

```
a = rand(10) # Float64 array with 10 elements
b = copy(a) # b == a is true, but b === a is false
ar = reinterpret(Float32,a)
foo(ar,a) # I'd like this to return true
foo(reinterpret(Float64,ar),b) # I'd like this to return false, even if reinterpret(Float64,ar) == b
```

I've tested `reinterpret(Float64,ar) === a` but it returns `false`.

For SubArrays this is achieved through `parent(subofA) === A`, which returns `true`. But I could provoke the same results for reinterpreted arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`reinterpret` only changes type-interpretation of the same memory block, so the solution is to compare pointers: `foo(x,y) = pointer(x) == pointer(y)`.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly more robust solution is:

```
data_id(A::StridedArray) = A === parent(A) ? UInt(pointer(A)) : data_id(parent(A))
data_id(A::AbstractArray) = A === parent(A) ? object_id(A) : data_id(parent(A))
might_share_data(A, B) = data_id(A) == data_id(B)
```

This still uses pointers to compare `Array`, but it will also handle SubArrays where the first element is offset.

```
julia> A = rand(3,4)
       B = view(A, 2:3, 2:3);

julia> pointer(A) == pointer(B)
false

julia> might_share_data(A, B)
true
```

Whereas just comparing the `pointer`s will have some false-negatives, this method will have some false-positives.  This approach will also work for *any* array type; some arrays don't implement pointer and will throw an error if you try to use it.

```
julia> C = view(A, [2,3], [2,3]);

julia> pointer(C)
ERROR: conversion to pointer not defined for SubArray{Float64,2,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1}},false}
 in pointer(::SubArray{Float64,2,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1}},false}) at ./abstractarray.jl:736

julia> might_share_data(A, C)
true
```

Comment: This is complicated enough that we really need a function to do this for you.